# The incidence matrix of a weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory

How to correctly build the incidence matrix of a undirected weighted graph? May you show a little example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An incidence matrix $M$ is a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{|V| \times |E|}$, where $M_{ij} = 1$ if vertex $i$ is incident to edge $j$, and $M_{ij} = 0$ otherwise.

You can replace the indicator value of $1$ with the edge weight instead.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Sorry, that I has replied too late.

Comment: I don't know whether this is standard, but in order to retain the property that $B^TB=L$, the Laplacian, I found that I needed to give the edges arbitrary orientations, as I've read is done in the unweighted case, then define $B_{i,j}$ as $\sqrt{w_{i,j}$ if there's an arc from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$, $-\sqrt{w_{i,j}$ if there's an arc from vertex $j$ to vertex $i$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: The above deciphered: $\sqrt{w_{i,j}}$  if there′s an arc from vertex i to vertex j, $-\sqrt{w_{i,j}}$ if there′s an arc from vertex j to vertex i , and $0$ otherwise

Answer (score 6):

Although this question has already been resolved, I would like to add an additional comment since the current responses are, in my opinion, unsatisfactory.

### The Unweighted Case

Following the notation of Biyikoglu et al., the incidence matrix $\nabla$ of an unweighted graph $G(V, E)$ is a $(|E| \times|V|)$ matrix defined by
$$
\nabla_{e, v}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-1 & \text{if $x$ is the initial vertex of edge $e$}\\
+1 & \text{if $x$ is the terminal vertex of edge $e$} \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$

Note that this is equivalent to

$$
\nabla_{e, v}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-\sqrt{A_e} & \text{if $x$ is the initial vertex of edge $e$}\\
+\sqrt{A_e} & \text{if $x$ is the terminal vertex of edge $e$} \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$. One crucial property of this matrix is that it satisfies the following relation

$$
\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{\nabla}^{\top} \mathbf{\nabla}
$$

where $L$ is the Laplacian matrix of $G$

$$
L_{x y}=\sum_{e \in E} \nabla_{e x} \nabla_{e y}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-1 & \text { if } x y \in E \\
d(x) & \text { if } x=y \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$
Equivalently, 
$$L = D - A$$
where $D$ is the degree matrix.

### The Weighted Case

Now, if we consider a weighted graph $G(V, W)$, we would like similar properties. Since the Laplacian for the weighted case is defined as

$$L = D - W$$

(note that we replaced the adjacency matrix with the weight matrix)

We would like to find a $(|E| \times|V|)$ matrix $\nabla$ such that

$$
\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{\nabla}^{\top} \mathbf{\nabla}
$$

Fixing an arbitrary orientation, the matrix defined by

$$
\nabla_{e, v}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-\sqrt{W_e} & \text{if $x$ is the initial vertex of edge $e$}\\
+\sqrt{W_e} & \text{if $x$ is the terminal vertex of edge $e$} \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$

satisfies the desired relation.

### Refs

Biyikoglu, T., Leydold, J., & Stadler, P. F. (2007). Laplacian eigenvectors of graphs: Perron-Frobenius and Faber-Krahn type theorems. Springer.

Kelner, J. (2007). An Algorithmist’s Toolkit: Lecture Notes. Lecture 2. MIT.

Answer (score 0):

I found a example in the following lecture (p.23):

https://www.fd.cvut.cz/personal/nagyivan/MatModEk/MME_Lectures.pdf

Comment: The link is not available

Comment: I've updated the link

Comment: Unavailable again. Note that this is the perfect example of the [problems with link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).